# Windows 7/ Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot. Ubuntu not booting

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my formatted and partitioned external hard drive M: while Windows is my primary OS on C:. It said my installation was successful and it prompted a reboot of my machine. When it rebooted, it gave an error that Windows did not successfully load due to an error in the wubildr.mbr file on the Linux boot disk.I fixed the error by using the bcdedit /delete {****} command under cmd run as an administrator. It fixed the conflict. When I try to boot into Linux using the 'esc' key upon startup and selecting the M: drive to boot from, it pauses for a second and then just boots up in Windows. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for comments. Still have to hit 'esc' for menu, but boots right up after. Simple fix, don't try to install from USB. Install from DVD drive

Answer (score 4):

After you have fixed the issues of booting Windows, it has replaced the Ubuntu's grub with Windows boot manager. You will have to recover your grub. The easiest way is:

- Step 0: Live boot into ubuntu.
- Step 1: Add launchpad repo. for boot-repair

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  ```
- Step 2: Run boot-repair `you@your-pc~$ boot-repair` and choose default option

That should fix your problem. Tell me how it goes. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

boot from ubuntu cd & then do like when you've been installing it & when the wizard asks you to chose replace the current ubuntu os, check repair checkbox & continue

Answer (score 0):

[njs](https://askubuntu.com/users/279492/njs)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/491074/299691) is the one you should be following if you just want to fix your problem.
If you also want to know what's happening try this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492)